# Symfony form - not able to collect POST values

Tags: php, symfony

Im having trouble trying to get POST values from a simple HTML form in symfony 2. This is what my controller method does:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/process-login/", name="process login")
     * @Method("POST")
     */
    public function processLoginAction()
    {
        $name     = $this->request->request->get('username');
        $password = $this->request->request->get('password');

        $em    = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id FROM AppBundle:Admin u WHERE u.name = :name AND u.password = :password')
                    ->setParameter('name', $name)
                    ->setParameter('password', $password);

        $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult();

        if($result < 1)
        {
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Incorrect login details');
            $action = $this->redirectToRoute('login');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->start();
            $this->session->set('admin', $name);
            $action = $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
        }

        return $action;
    }
```

Whenever I process the form I get the error 
No route found for "POST /process-login".

Where could be the issue? 
P.S. works with GET

Comment: delete the `/` from the end of the route. `@Route("/process-login"...`. it should be the case. also run `php app/console router:debug` to see if the route is  even identified by Symfony.

Comment: haha worked after I removed the slash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because of the slash in the end. 
delete the / from the end of the route.

```
/**
 * @Route("/process-login", name="process login")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
```

it should be the case.

also run

```
php app/console router:debug
```

to see if the route is even identified by Symfony2.